# Spring RESTful GET method with same parameters and different return type

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, rest, spring-mvc

I work with `Java/ Sprig MVC RESTful app` and the client consumes it. I have 2 `RESTful` methods in the same input parameters and different return types. The methods are provided below,

```
// this method should return the `String` 
@RequestMapping(value = "wallets/{currencyName}/{walletName}", method = RequestMethod.GET
            , produces = "text/html")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getAddressWithCurrencyAndWalletName(@PathVariable("currencyName") String currencyName,
                                                                      @PathVariable("walletName") String walletName) {

        logger.info("The currency name is {} and wallet name is {}", currencyName, walletName);
        WalletInfo walletInfo = walletService.getWalletInfoWithCurrencyAndWalletName(currencyName, walletName);

        if (Objects.isNull(walletInfo)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        String address = walletInfo.getAddress();
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(address, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    // this method should return the `Long` 
    @RequestMapping(value = "wallets/{currencyName}/{walletName}", method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = "text/html")
    public ResponseEntity<Long> getWalletIdWithCurrencyAndWalletName(@PathVariable("currencyName") String currencyName,
                                                                     @PathVariable("walletName") String walletName) {

        logger.info("The currency name is {} and wallet name is {}", currencyName, walletName);
        WalletInfo walletInfo = walletService.getWalletInfoWithCurrencyAndWalletName(currencyName, walletName);

        if (Objects.isNull(walletInfo)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Long>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        Long walletId = walletInfo.getId();
        return new ResponseEntity<Long>(walletId, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

In the client-side, I have UI like this,

[image]

If the `Balance` button is clicked, I would like to open a new page with `URL` of `http://localhost:63342/WalletClient/balance.html?walletId=someValue` and I would like to use the 2nd RESTful method for the very purpose. I imagine the client code to be like;

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var walletName, selectedCurrency;

    // generic request function with the URL, method name and
    // the request (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE etc) data
    function request(url, method, data) {
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl + url,
            // url: url,
            method: method,
            data: data
        })
    }

    // some code 
    // we have the walletName and selectedCurrency values extracted 

    $("#balance").click(function () {

            console.log("Open the balance page");

            var url = "/rest/wallets/?" + "currencyName=" + selectedCurrency + "&" + "walletName=" + walletName;

            // get the wallet Id from the cureny name and the wallet name
            request(url, "GET").done(function (data) {
                window.open("/WalletClient/balance.html?walletId=" + data);
            });
        });
}
```

The `URL` comes from the `RESTful` method and I expect it to return the `Long`. I have few questions in this scenarios,

a. Will it work as the same `GET` request could potentially return the `String` and `Long`?

b. is the `data` is already the `String` or the `Long` or I need to do something on over it?

Obvously, I can write it like `window.open("/WalletClient/balance.html?" + "currencyName=" + selectedCurrency + "&" + "walletName=" + walletName);`.
However, in this case the `currencyName` and the `walletName` will be exposed to the user and I would much prefer to hide it in the `URL`.

`UPDATE`

I changed the code to accomodatean optional parameter to distinct between the `Long` and the `String`,

```
 /**
     * get the wallet address with the currency name and the wallet name
     * 
     * returns the Long value for the walletInfo 
     * curl -i -H "Accept: text/html" http://localhost:8080/rest/wallets/bitcoin/puut | json
     *
     * 
     * returns the String value for the walletInfo address 
     * curl -i -H "Accept: text/html" http://localhost:8080/rest/wallets/bitcoin/puut/true | json
     * 
     * @param currencyName
     * @param walletName
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "wallets/{currencyName}/{walletName}", method = RequestMethod.GET
            , produces = "text/html")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAddressWithCurrencyAndWalletName(@PathVariable("currencyName") String currencyName,
                                                                 @PathVariable("walletName") String walletName
            , @RequestParam(value = "address", required = false) boolean address) {

        logger.info("The currency name is {} and wallet name is {}", currencyName, walletName);
        WalletInfo walletInfo = walletService.getWalletInfoWithCurrencyAndWalletName(currencyName, walletName);

        if (Objects.isNull(walletInfo)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        // address values is expected 
        if(address){

            String addressValue = walletInfo.getAddress();
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(addressValue, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        else {
            Long walletId = walletInfo.getId();
            return new ResponseEntity<Long>(walletId, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```

The client side `URL` will be like this,

```
var url = "/rest/wallets/?" + "currencyName=" + selectedCurrency + "&" + "walletName=" + walletName;
```

Is this correct now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your method and return `ResponseEntity<?>` type.
It would be:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public ResponseEntity<?> yourMethod(...) {
    // business-logic
    if (some condition) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(address, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else if (...) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Long>(walletId, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea. How do I modify the method to say, it will usually return the `Long` unless I provide a `boolean true`  and in that case, it will provide the `String`?

Comment: Yes, you can add an additional parameter that would allow to select the return type or return both values Long and String (if you use a simple DTO object).

Comment: I updated the question and provided the code. Would you please have a look?

Comment: If you use '@PathVariable' in your controller you need to change your client code: var url = "/rest/wallets/" + selectedCurrency + "/" + walletName;

Comment: Great, I forget about this

Comment: Yes, if you add '?adress=true' parameter to your URL it will return String if not - Long

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152056/discussion-between-artin-and-shchipunov).